# Running stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What's the best way to know which stored procedure are currently running in a database.

I have a stored procedure which basically calls other 3 and passes them some parameters and these 3 stored procedures take a long time to complete... I would like to know which one is running...

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008 there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can also use [SQL profiler](http://www.guidanceshare.com/index.php?title=How_To_Use_SQL_Profiler&printable=yes) to get information in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Use Activity Monitor to detect what is currently running on your database. 
The **Command** column might indicate which stored procedure is currently running.

To help you monitor whats stored procedure is running I would suggest creating a SQL Job to run those 3 stored procedures seperately as steps. That way you can place an **email alert** step in between them so that you know when each one has completed.

This shouldn't be too difficult to setup in SQL Server Agent.

EDIT: SQL Profiler is an option, but this will have an impact on performance as you will be monitoring the live database, plus you indicated that the stored procedures take a while to run so you would want those times to increase.  IMO I think a simple email alert, or some other form of notification which could be built at the end of each stored procedure would be you best option.

e.g. An simple insert to a log file with a timestamp indication when each stored procedure has finished.